# How to find Set difference with custom Comparator or equals method?

Tags: java, set, comparator

I want to find the difference between two `Set<T>` using a different equality metric than that used by the class `T`, for example a custom `Comparator<T>`

For example, I have a class `Animal`, which usually tests equality using the species of the `Animal`

```
public class Animal {
    public String species;
    public String genus;

    public Animal(String species, String genus){
        this.species = species;
        this.genus = genus;
    }

    public boolean equals(Animal other){
        return other.species.equals(this.species);
    }
}
```

I have two `List<Animal>` and I'd like to find the intersection of shared genus between the two lists.

Usually, I'd convert the `List` to `Set` and use [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) to find the intersection. But here, that would give the intersection of shared species, not shared genus.

I'd like to use something like the `GenusComparator` to define equality for the intersection.

```
public class GenusComparator implements Comparator<Animal>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Animal animal1, Animal animal2) {
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(animal1.genus, animal2.genus);
    }

}
```

This is just a simple example to explain what I'm trying to do, not the actual classes in my application.

Two possible solutions that I have found are

1. Wrap the class and override the equals method
2. Use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a custom Comparator

Are there other ways I've missed so far, and what are the possible pros and cons of these solutions?

Comment: So, if set 1 has `Jaguar/Panthera`, `Margay/Leopardus`, and `Tiger/Panthera`, and set 2 has `Bobcat/Lynx`, `Cougar/Puma`, and `Leopard/Panthera`, what do you expect result to be? If you do the `TreeSet(GenusComparator).addAll(set1).retainAll(set2)` combo, you'd get `Jaguar/Panthera`, but the set of animals with common genus is really `Jaguar/Panthera`, `Tiger/Panthera`, and `Leopard/Panthera`.

Comment: I would expect the intersection to be X / Panthera, where X is either Jaguar, Tiger, or Leopard. It would consider two animals with the same genus equal regardless of the species.

Comment: It is a mistake to write a custom `equals()` method for a class without also writing a companion `hashCode()` method for it.

Comment: @Cecilia Then go with the `TreeSet` solution. Fastest, easiest, lowest memory footprint.

Comment: @Andreas if you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @scottb Species names are globally unique, even for species of different genus, so unique check on species only is fine. E.g. Species `Jaguar` is genus `Panthera`, and there are no other species called `Jaguar`.

Comment: @scottb Thanks for pointing the overloading/overriding difference plus the need for a hashCode method. This isn't actually a class that I am using, so the logic of the equals method isn't too crucial, but your other points are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, is to simple use a `TreeSet` with the `GenusComparator`.

You have to convert both sets to `TreeSet(GenusComparator)` for the `retainAll()` to work correctly.

I fixed `equals()` and added `hashCode()` and `toString()`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Animal> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Animal("Jaguar", "Panthera"),
                                                       new Animal("Margay", "Leopardus"),
                                                       new Animal("Tiger", "Panthera")));
        Set<Animal> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Animal("Bobcat", "Lynx"),
                                                       new Animal("Cougar", "Puma"),
                                                       new Animal("Leopard", "Panthera")));
        TreeSet<Animal> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>(new GenusComparator());
        treeSet1.addAll(set1);
        TreeSet<Animal> treeSet2 = new TreeSet<>(new GenusComparator());
        treeSet2.addAll(set2);
        treeSet1.retainAll(treeSet2);
        System.out.println(treeSet1);
    }
}
class Animal {
    public String species;
    public String genus;

    public Animal(String species, String genus) {
        this.species = species;
        this.genus = genus;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Animal && this.species.equals(((Animal)obj).species);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.species.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.species + "/" + this.genus;
    }
}
class GenusComparator implements Comparator<Animal> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Animal animal1, Animal animal2) {
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(animal1.genus, animal2.genus);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[Jaguar/Panthera]
```